# Custom UITableViewCell delegating for its subviews?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a `custom cell` with a `textfield` as a subview. Is it legal to set the cell as the delegate for the `textfield`?

I want to set the cell as the delegate because it's the parent view, but when I do this, the app crashes. I suppose it's because `table view dequeue cells` and maybe that's why the delegate reference got lost in between. 
So, I tried to set the delegate in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to make sure it's freshly set every time, but it still won't work.

Do I really have to move a level up and let the `tableview controller` be the delegate of cell's subviews? or am I missing something else?

crash report outputs:

```
>libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
>
0x32ed4f78:  ldr    r3, [r4, #8]
>
```

initWithStyle I have

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier type: (NSString *)cellType
{

self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Custom Cell" owner:self options:nil];
    self = [nibArray lastObject];

    self.cellType = [NSString stringWithString:cellType];
    self.contentText.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    self.detailLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    self.contentText.delegate = self;
}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the custom cell as delegate to the text field in the cell is not a problem at all. The table view will reuse some cells as and when required but that will not affect anything. I guess you are missing something else. Maybe I could help if you post the error you get when it crashes and corresponding pieces of your code.

Comment: In your case, the error "objc_msgSend" seems to occur because that object is released. You may need to post the full error message to know which method is causing the error. Also, like endy mentioned, you   don't really need to assign the delegate in your table view delegate/datasource methods.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the `delegate` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath.`

In your `UITableViewCell` subclass add the `UITextField` in the `initWithStyle` method and then set the `delegate` to `self` in there.

Comment: thanks for your reply! My first approach was setting it in initWithStyle, but then it failed, so I moved to cellForRow, but either way they aren't working properly